# iPhone microphone works selectively

Tags: iphone, microphone

It started with Whatsapp - people could not hear my voice. There was no sound in recording videos to Instagram stories. Soon after that, the microphone stopped working in Teams, Facetime and Google Duo. All the time, I could use the phone normally and record videos with camera - no issues with sound. It does not make a difference if I use loudspeaker or not.

In summary, the microphone works e.g. in:

- talking on the phone
- recording videos
- talking to Siri
- using speech recognition in Whatsapp when dictating messages

It does not work in:

- dictating voice messages in iPhone's standard voice recorder app. If
  I yell at the microphone, you can barely hear something against a
  static noise
- sending video or sound messages in Whatsapp, Google Duo etc.
- talking or using videophone in Whatsapp, Facetime, Google Duo

I have done the following in this order:

1. cleaned and checked the microphone, removed protective case. Checked sound levels.
2. checked that microphone is allowed in all the apps mentioned
3. updated iOs and Whatsapp to most recent versions
4. factory reset iPhone by deleting all the contents and reinstalling
   it from iCloud backup

These had no effect on the issue. I don't think there is anything physically wrong in the mic since it works fine in the above mentioned cases.

Even more mysterious is that if I plug in iPhone's headset, Whatsapp, Teams etc. all work fine. Phone is iPhone 8. Would be interesting to know what causes the issue or if there is a way of fixing it.

Comment: There might be a lot of dust accumulated in the microphones at the bottom.

Comment: “ dictating voice messages in iPhone's standard voice recorder app. If I yell at the microphone, you can barely hear something against a static noise” contradicts the nothing is wrong with the device you summarized  - have you had it looked at by a repair tech or done a backup and erase install to retest the built in app without any third party apps installed?

Comment: Yes, that was the fourth point. Completely reset iPhone and reinstalled from backup. Whatsapp has had updates before and after that. Regarding the earlier response on dust in the microphone: if that were the case, I would have the same issue using the phone. iPhone does not have a separate microphone for Whatsup.